# Adding new Module AngularJS FountainJS (Yeoman)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, yeoman

I'm using **[fountainJS](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-webapp)** and I'm facing a problem with this seeder of `AngularJS`. I think I can develop with this scaffold because in addition to come with several pre-installed things, it will make things easier for me later.

[My *architecture*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipx29.png)

and the files of my module "eventsList" are this:

**./src/app/eventsList/eventsList.js**

```
class EventsListController{
    constructor(){
        this.hola = "hola";

        this.event = {
            name: "das",
            place: "",
            day: "",
            hour: ""
        };  

        this.events = [
            {
                name: "nombre alerta",
                place: "lugar",
                day: "dia"
            },
            {
                name: "nombre alerta 222",
                place: "lugar",
                day: "dia"
            }
        ];

    };
};

export const eventsList = {
  templateurl: 'app/eventsList/eventsList.html',
  controller: EventsListController
};
```

**./src/app/eventsList/index.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';

import {eventsList} from './eventsList';

export const eventsListModule = 'eventsList';

angular
.module(eventsListModule, [])
.component('eventsList', eventsList);
```

And the html of the component in **./src/app/eventsList/eventsList.html**

```
<div class="techs">
    <div>
        {{$ctrl.hola}}
        {{$ctrl.event.name}}
        {{$ctrl.events}}
        <select ng-options="evento in $ctrl.events">
            <option value="">Choose City</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the main view of my app and my directive of my module. in **./src/app/main.html**

```
<events-list></events-list>
<div class="main-container">
  <fountain-header></fountain-header>
  <main class="main">
    <fountain-title></fountain-title>
    <fountain-techs></fountain-techs>
  </main>
  <fountain-footer></fountain-footer>
</div>
```

Then I register my module in in **./src/index.js** of app, in the root of my project like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';

import {techsModule} from './app/techs/index';
import {eventsListModule} from './app/eventsList/index';
import 'angular-ui-router';
import routesConfig from './routes';

import {main} from './app/main';
import {header} from './app/header';
import {title} from './app/title';
import {footer} from './app/footer';

import './index.less';

angular
  .module('app', [techsModule, eventsListModule, 'ui.router'])
  .config(routesConfig)
  .component('app', main)
  .component('fountainHeader', header)
  .component('fountainTitle', title)
  .component('fountainFooter', footer);
```

When I go to the browser it's not working as I expect because I don't see the html of my module, but I think I'm on the way because my module is in the DOM and with his isolate scope.

The **result** in browser:

[image]

Any sugestions to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, you need to replace `templateurl` with `templateUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have forgotten to add `<events-list></events-list>` in your html.

Comment: No, i have my directive "events-list" in the html but nothing (when I copied the code the first line was not paste in the post, I'll fix right now